# I keep getting this error "angular.js:TypeError: Cannot read property 'pages' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[The error in console after console.log(data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMQs0.png)

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['**']);
});

app.controller("myCtrl",["$scope","$window", "$http",
    function($scope, $window, $http,) {

      //variable to get input
      var input = $('input');
      var search = $("#search");
      var form = $('form');

      //Function for random wiki article
      $scope.Random = function() {
          $window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random", "_blank");
    };


     //function for searching wiki article 
     $scope.search = function() {
       $scope.result = [];
       var title = input.val();
         var api = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=";
         //var cb = "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
         var page = "https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=";
       $http.jsonp(api + title, {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'}).then(function(data) { var results = data.query.pages;
    console.log(data);            
      angular.forEach(results, function(v,k)  {
        $scope.results.push({title: v.title, body: v.extract, page: page + v.pageid})
      })
    });
   };
    }]);
```

This is my angular script.I have also used `$scedelegateProvider` to make the URL in white-list. It is used for calling the Wikipedia API.Help me please to resolve this issue.

Comment: `data.query` is `undefined` thus you are getting the error

Comment: @Satpal how can i resolve this?

Comment: Log your `data` to console and see what you get there i think it should be `data.data.query.pages` instead

Comment: @jitender getting same error..how can i resolve it?

Comment: what you get in console when your write `console.log(data)`

Comment: @jitender same error every time.

Comment: You need to write `console.log(data)` as the very first thing within the `then`-callback.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen ok..I did that..and then?

Comment: Report to us what it prints out in the browser console.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I added a link to the image of the error..please see.

Comment: var results = data.query.pages gives you an object, and can you expand the  pages object in the console

Comment: @KevinRED so what's the fix?

Comment: Could you post your html code?

Comment: And I recommend you do not use 'JQuery' with 'Angularjs'. If you really want to use 'JQuery', then using 'Javascript' instead of 'JQuery'.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested like below and my result was fine.

**CODE**

```
var title = 'Angularjs';
var api = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=';

var url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(api+title);

$http.jsonp(url, {
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',     // add this
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.data.query.pages);
});
```

**CONSOLE**

[image]

Try this. :)

Comment: @VikasSaraf My pleasure! :D